# How can I delete everything from XXXX to the last line before an empty line in a text document?

Tags: batch, text-editing, editing

Given a text document with multiple instances of the content:

```
XXXX
random number of lines with random text
other random text
more random text
random text
'blank line'
```

i want to delete everything between XXXX and the random text in the line before the blank line, and insert a comma before the random text so it looks like this:

```
XXXX,random text
'blank line'
```

How can I do this with a single command?

I currently use sublime text 3 and notepad++ on windows 10 but this question is platform agnostic. I'll use anything that works, thanks!

Comment: It has to be a oneline command?

Comment: Are "things" and "stuff" always the same, or are they also random text?

Comment: Is XXXX the beginning of the text file, a specific line or specific text?

Comment: 'Things' and 'stuff' are random text. 'XXXX' is specific text. Basically, this is a long list with stuff in the middle of each entry that needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to scoberry5 from reddit:

Here are the parts I think you want:

XXXX
some character, including newline, any number of times (as few as possible)
one or more non-newlines (as many as possible)
end of line, followed by a we-are-at-the-end-of-line marker

You should be able to replace (XXXX).*?([^\n]+)\n$ with \1,\2\n , as in https://regex101.com/r/bldhDZ/1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "things" and "stuff" are always the same, you could use this:

**Find what**: `XXXX\r\nthings\r\nstuff.*?\r\n(.*?)\r\n\r\n`
**Replace with**: `XXXX, \1\r\n\r\n`

Where:

- `\r\n\` : stands for the Windows end-line (carriage-return, line-feed)
- `.*?` : 0 or more character, non-greedy search
- `()` : defines a group
- `\1` : the contents of the matched group.

Here is my test-case:

[image]

And here is the result after clicking Replace All:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Things and stuff were meant to be a random number of lines with random text. When I removed '\r\nthings\r\nstuff` it correctly selected everything from XXXX to the next empty line, but stopped preserving the last line with text before the next empty line. Incidentally, is there a resource you would recommend to get good at regex?

Comment: A little adjustment will probably make your Find and Replace strings work - what were they? For regex learning materials, just google for "regex tutorial" and take your pick.

Answer (score 1):

With Notepad:

- Find what: `XXXX\K\R(^[^'].+$\R){1,}`
- Replace with: `\r\n`
- Search mode: Regular Expression

**Before**

[image: Input]

**After**

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks!


Unfortunately this code seems really inconsistent. It worked exactly once and then after that it would delete everything from the first XXXX to the very last line before an empty line in the page. 


Actually now when I hit replace, it's just cycling between highlighting the contents of the first, second and third instance of XXXX all the way to the final line before the last.


Also, it is highlighting from the very first instance of the XXXX to the last empty line before the very bottom of the page instead of stopping before the last line with text before an empty line.

Comment: @user1560100 I can't reproduce what the issue. The lines are found, then replaced. See the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCZD7.gif).